# eingenvalues and adjoints

Tags: linear-algebra

> \begin{align}T_1 \,^* T_1 &= S_2 \,^* T_2\,^* S_1\,^* S_1 T_2 S_2\\
> &=S_2 ^{-1}T_2 \,^*T_2 S_2 \end{align}
>
> This implies that $T_1\,^*T_1$ and $T_2\,^*T_2$ have the same eigenvalues (and that the corresponding space of eigenvectors have the same dimensions).

How does the equality imply the statement?

Comment: I have typed out your image using MathJax, in future please do this instead of posting an image as some users are not able to view images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $A,B$ and $S$ are square matrices of the same size, that $S$ is invertible and that $A=S^{-1}BS$. Then we have

$Ax= \mu x \iff S^{-1}BS= \mu S^{-1}Sx \iff BSx= \mu Sx.$

If $x \ne 0$, then $Sx \ne 0$, since $S$ is invertible. Thus we have shown:

if $ \mu $ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $ \mu $ is an eigenvalue of $B$.

Since $B=SAS^{-1}$, we get with similar arguments:

if $ \mu $ is an eigenvalue of $B$, then $ \mu $ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: we still need to prove that dim(E(μ,A))=dim(E(μ,B)), thus to complete the proof let's suppose that E(μ,A)=span(e1,e2,...,en) where e1,e2,....,en is an orthonormal basis,  using the equivalence relation that you mentioned above, we're led to the conclusion that span(Se1,Se2,....,Sen) is contained in E(μ,B)

Comment: and since S is invertible dim(span(Se1,Se2,..,Sen))=dim(rangeS)=span(e1,e2,....,en),so this implies that dim(E(μ,A)<=dim(E(μ,B)) for all eigenvalues,and we also know that A,B are positive operators so the spectral theorem tells us that A and B are diagonalisable which would in turn imply that dimV=dim(E(μ1,A))+...+dim(E(μn,A))=dim(E(μ1,B))+...+dim(E(μn,B)) which concludes to dim(E(μ,A)=dim(E(μ,B)) for all eigenvalues